# Show that the product of two uniformly continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ need not be uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that I have to rely on the definition: 
A function $f : E \rightarrow T$ is said to be uniformly continuous on $E$ if and only if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$d_T(f(p),f(q)) < ε$ if $p,q ∈ E$ and $d_S(p,q) < δ$.

I know that if $f(x) = x$  for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous but do not prove it. I must provide a proof. $|f(x)-f(y)| = |x + y|$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$. True but that does not help my proof. Please help me prove that it is uniformly continuous!

Comment: Hint: Is $x^2$ uniformly continuous?

Comment: Secondly, is $|f(x) - f(y)|$ really equal to $|x+y|$?